# OpenCV, Java: Color Detection in a certain specified area

Tags: android, opencv

I currently have this image:

[image]

I managed to detect the black object. Now i want to detect the green object, but i only want the application to look for the green object **below** the black object. I already have the code to detect the green tape and its working. Just need to set it so that its only in the area below the black object.

Resulting image should still look like this:
[image]

P.S some of the variables are named "Blue", rest assured its using Green scalar values.

Code:

```
//Detect Black
private Bitmap findCombine(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
    Bitmap roiBitmap = null;
    Scalar green = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
    Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);

    Mat roiTmp = sourceMat.clone();
    bitmapWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    Log.e("bitmapWidth", String.valueOf(bitmapWidth));
    final Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
    sourceMat.copyTo(hsvMat);

    // convert mat to HSV format for Core.inRange()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Scalar lowerb = new Scalar(85, 50, 40);         // lower color border for BLUE
    Scalar upperb = new Scalar(135, 255, 255);      // upper color border for BLUE

    Scalar lowerblack = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);         // lower color border for BLACK
    Scalar upperblack = new Scalar(180, 255, 40);      // upper color border for BLACK

    Scalar testRunL = new Scalar(60, 50, 40); // lower Green   83 100 51
    Scalar testRunU = new Scalar(90, 255, 255); // upper Green

    Core.inRange(hsvMat, lowerblack, upperblack, roiTmp);   // select only blue pixels
    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RotatedRect> boundingRects = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(roiTmp, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
        RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);

        double rectangleArea = boundingRect.size.area();

        // test min ROI area in pixels
        if (rectangleArea > 1300 && rectangleArea < 500000) {//400000
            Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
            boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);
            Rect rect3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));

            Log.e("blackArea", String.valueOf(rect3.area()));
            // test horizontal ROI orientation
            if (rect3.height > rect3.width) {
                Imgproc.rectangle(sourceMat, rect3.tl(), rect3.br(), green, 3);
                xBlack = rect3.br().x;
                xBlackCenter = (rect3.br().x+ rect3.tl().x) /2;
                yBlack = rect3.br().y;//bottom
                battHeight = (rect3.br().y - rect3.tl().y); //batt height in pixel
                Log.e("BLACKBR, TL", String.valueOf(rect3.br().y) + "," + String.valueOf(rect3.tl().y));
            }

        }

    }
    roiBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat.cols(), sourceMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(sourceMat, roiBitmap);







//Set area to detect green
    Point leftPoint = new Point(0, yBlack); //far left, black object height
    Point rightPoint = new Point(roiBitmap.getWidth(), roiBitmap.getHeight()); //btm right of entire bitmap

    Rect bottomRect = new Rect(leftPoint, rightPoint);
    double rectWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 0;
    double rectHeight = sourceBitmap.getHeight() - yBlack;
    Log.e("rectWidth", String.valueOf(rectWidth));
    Log.e("rectHeight", String.valueOf(rectHeight));

    Mat sourceMatT = new Mat(roiBitmap.getWidth(), roiBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(roiBitmap,sourceMatT);

    Bitmap C = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMatT.cols(), sourceMatT.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(sourceMatT, C);

    Mat dumbMat = sourceMatT.clone();
    Log.e("sourceMatT, BottomRect","SMT "+ String.valueOf(sourceMatT.size()) + " bottomRect " + String.valueOf(bottomRect.size()));


    Mat cropMat = new Mat(dumbMat, bottomRect);
    ImageView imgCropped = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropped_image_view);

    //Utils.matToBitmap(cropMat,C);
    imgCropped.setImageBitmap(C);






//Detect Green
    Bitmap roiBitmap2 = null;
    Mat sourceMat2 = new Mat(C.getWidth(), C.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

    Utils.bitmapToMat(C, sourceMat2);
    Mat roiTmp2 = sourceMat2.clone();

    final Mat hsvMat2 = new Mat();
    sourceMat.copyTo(hsvMat2);

    // convert mat to HSV format for Core.inRange()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat2, hsvMat2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
    Core.inRange(hsvMat2, testRunL, testRunU, roiTmp2);   // select only blue pixels

    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RotatedRect> boundingRects2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(roiTmp2, contours2, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour2 : contours2) {
        MatOfPoint2f areaPoints2 = new MatOfPoint2f(contour2.toArray());
        RotatedRect boundingRect2 = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints2);

        double rectangleArea2 = boundingRect2.size.area();

        // test min ROI area in pixels
        if (rectangleArea2 > 40) { //214468.32402064091 // 20000
            Point rotated_rect_points2[] = new Point[4];
            boundingRect2.points(rotated_rect_points2);
            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points2));
            Log.e("area green", String.valueOf(boundingRect2.size.area()));
            // test vertical ROI orientation


            if (rect.width > rect.height) {


                if (numRect < 2) {
                    Imgproc.rectangle(sourceMat2, rect.tl(), rect.br(), green, 3);
                    xBlue = (rect.br().x + rect.tl().x) / 2; //center
                    yBlue = rect.br().y; //bottom

                    Log.e("GREEN br,tl", String.valueOf(rect.br().y) + "  " + String.valueOf(rect.tl().y));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Point firstPoint = new Point(xBlackCenter, yBlack);
    Point secondPoint = new Point(xBlackCenter, yBlue);
    Point middlePoint = new Point(firstPoint.x,
            firstPoint.y + 0.5 * (secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y));

    Scalar lineColor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
    int lineWidth = 3;

    Scalar textColor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
    //height of bounce = BattHeight IRL / battHeihgt Pixel * line Height Pixel
    double lineHeightCm = (4.65 / battHeight) * findHeight(yBlack, yBlue);
    Log.e("PixelBatt/PixelBounce", "BattH: " + battHeight + " find height " + String.valueOf(findHeight(xBlack, xBlue)) + "!");
    Log.e("Blacky-blueY", String.valueOf(xBlue - xBlack));
    Imgproc.line(sourceMat2, firstPoint, secondPoint, lineColor, lineWidth);
    Imgproc.putText(sourceMat2, String.valueOf(lineHeightCm), middlePoint,
            Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3.5, textColor);


    roiBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat2.cols(), sourceMat2.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(sourceMat2, roiBitmap2);

    TextView tvR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvR);
    tvR.setText("Bounce Height = " + lineHeightCm + "cm");


    return roiBitmap2;
}
```

Error:

> CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem, the error or finding the green object?

Comment: The problem I'm having is to have the application to look for the green object ONLY below the black object, currently its searching the entire image which i do not want.  I have no issues finding green / black, I only want to detect green in a specific area. Lets say there are 2 green object, one below one above the black object. I only want the green BELOW the black object to be detected

Comment: You could just run your detection on the _below_ part of the image.

Comment: I dont know how to run it on the "below" part of the image...

Comment: You could extract the Region Of Interest, in this case below part, by using [Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/core/Rect.html). If you are not sure about the top-left corner for the rect, you could find the black object first, then use the y value of one of its bottom corners and x as the start of the image.

Comment: @RickM. , that's basically what im having error with, extracting the below part using Rect seems to be giving me error. If you take a look at the code there's a comment that says `//Set area to detect green` which is the section of the code where i tried to extract the "below" area, but is causing an issue shown in the question as well.

Comment: I don't understand why you do so many matToBitmap and bitmapToMat conversions, can you add comments to your code regarding the reason? Which line does the exception come on, can you add that in your code too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to find green objects in specific area: You can find green contours on entire image, then just test it coordinates relative to black rectangle. Something like that:

At first - find black rectangle.

```
Rect blackRect = findBlackRect();
```

Then find contours of ALL green objects (same way as You find black):

```
// find green contours
List<MatOfPoint> greenContours = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(roiMat, greenContours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Then test what of green contours laying below of black rect (has grater Y coord)

```
// find appropriate bounding rectangles
for (MatOfPoint contour : greenContours) {
    MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
    RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);

    Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
    boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);

    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));

    // test top left Y coord of bounding rectangle of green contour grater than 
    // Y coord of top left of black rectangle 
    if (rect.tl().y > blackRect.tl().y) {
        // that is green contour under black rectangle
        // just draw it
        Imgproc.rectangle(sourceMat, rect.tl(), rect.br(), green, 3);
    }
}
```

And so on...